# How to append or Prepending HTML Tags to SocialEngine Form Element?

Tags: html, forms, zend-framework, socialengine

I want a html form where I can group some element inside a div. I am using socialengine to create a form?

Answer (score 0):

After long research I got this solution it might be helpful for others.

```
class Mymodule_Form_Article_Filter extends Engine_Form{

public function init()
{
    $request = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRequest();

    $this->setDescription('Find article which you want..');
    $this->setAttrib('class', 'global_form_popup');

    //create a form element
    $this->addElement('Text', 'outcome', array(
        'label' => 'Search Outcome',
        'required' => false,
        'value' =>$request->getParam('outcome'),
        'class' => 'outcome-search'
    ));
    // create submit element
    $this->addElement('Button', 'submit', array(
        'label' => 'Filter Articles',
        'type' => 'submit',
        'class' => 'outcome-search'
    ));
    //wrapping to a div
    $this->addDisplayGroup(array('outcome', 'submit'), 'searchGroup');
    $group = $this->getDisplayGroup('searchGroup');

    $group->setDecorators(array(
        'FormElements',
        array('HtmlTag', array('tag' => 'div', 'class' => 'full-length-search'))
    ));

    }
}
```